# Nextjs: update state not work in interval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

This is my state:

```
const [time, setTime] = useState(10)
```

And this is my handler:

```
const runTimer = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            console.log(time)
            if (time > 0) {
                setTime(time - 1)
            } else {
                console.log("End")
            }
        }, 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval)
    }, [])
}
```

My log:

```
9
9
9
9
9
.
.
.
```

Why `setTime` doesn't work ?

`time` variable most increase per 1000 delay

Comment: I would recommend reading: [link](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/). It might come in handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you pass to `useEffect` has [closed over](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) the `timer` variable from the first time the component rendered.

Each time the component renders, the current value of the state is read and a `timer` variable is created with that value.

You aren't accessing that variable though. The `variable` you are accessing on the interval never changes, so every time you access it, it is still `10`.

---

State functions are passed the current value as an argument, so use that instead.

```
const Timer = () => {
    const [timer, setTime] = useState(10);
    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setTime(
                (currentTime) => {
                    if (currentTime > 0) {
                        return currentTime - 1;
                    } else {
                        console.log("End of interval");
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        return currentTime;
                    }
                }
            );
        }, 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval)
    }, [])
    return <p>{timer}</p>
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Where do you definition currentTime?

Comment: @RezMohsnei — On the 5th line.

Comment: Hooks are supposed to be called at the top level in the body of a function component or a custom hook - this is still definitely not a correct usage of `useEffect`.

Comment: So, i get this error: Argument of type '(currentTime: number) => number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<number>'.

Comment: @goto — Ah darn. I assumed the OP was just leaving out the return from the component for brevity but the name isn't even a valid component name.

Comment: @RezMohsnei — Then return from the else branch so it never returns `undefined`

Comment: @Quentin can you check this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70722073/nextjs-error-rendered-fewer-hooks-than-expected-this-may-be-caused-by-an-acci

Comment: There's a small typo on the `setTime` function call, should be `setTimer`.