# Nextjs: Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement

Tags: reactjs, next.js

This is my code:

```
const runTimer = () => {
    useInterval(() => {
        if (time == 1) {
            setResend(true)
        }
        setTime(time - 1);
    }, (time > 0) ? 1000 : null);

    return("Start")
}

return (
    <div>
        {resend && (
            <div className={styles.timer}>{runTimer()}</div>
        )}
    </div>
)
```

On `time == 1` and `setResend(false)` I get this error:

```
Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement.
```

I want to show my `div` after timer equal 1, and if I click on `div`, timer run again

> EDIT:

I change my code to this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setTime(
            (currentTime) => {
                if (currentTime > 0) {
                    return currentTime - 1;
                } else {
                    setResend(false)
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    return currentTime;
                }
            }
        );
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
}, [])
return <p>{time}</p>
```

But not work yet!

Comment: Do not put use hooks in plain javascript functions https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: @possum thank you. can you help me more? how can I change my code to solve it?

Comment: @possum I change my code, but not work yet

Comment: Can you please show us the full code for the component you have? Including the `setState`.