# Nextjs: create countdown OTP verify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

This is my `Login.tsx`

```
{!isVerify ? (
    // Login form
) : (
    <Verify data-phoneNumber={form.phoneNumber} data-countryCode={form.countryCode} />
)}
```

After send mobile with user, I change `isVerify` to `True` and `<Verify />` component show to user.

And this is my verify:

```
const runTimer = () => {
        useEffect(() => {
            const interval = setInterval(() => {
                console.log(time);
                setTime(
                    (currentTime) => {
                        if (currentTime > 0) {
                            return currentTime - 1;
                        } else {
                            setResend(false)
                            clearInterval(interval);
                            return currentTime;
                        }
                    }
                );
            }, 1000);
            return () => clearInterval(interval)
        }, [])
}

const runAgain = () => {
    runTimer()
}

return (
    <div>
        {runTimer()}
        <div onClick={(e) => runAgain(e)}>Run Again</div>
    </div>
)
```

For first time my timer work fine. but for second time not work! ( if I click on run again )

Comment: You cannot use `useEffect` conditionally. This is one of the rules of hooks. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: @Evert Can you help me more? I see the url, but I can't understand it

Comment: It's possible to rewrite your code to make it work, but it's _really important_ you lean how to use react & hooks before you use it. If you don't understand the above page, you are going to have trouble with react absolutely everywhere. Find more tutorials maybe?

Comment: @Evert I googling very lot. but I can't find anything about this problem

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is: don't google your problem, try to learn how hooks work. A `useEffect` statement inside a function is *not allowed* and breaks your application, but as a react dev you should try to learn why that is.

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70722073/nextjs-error-rendered-fewer-hooks-than-expected-this-may-be-caused-by-an-acci? Please refrain from posting the same question multiple times.